# Can we make it an option for users to show spoilers by default?

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

I appreciate that spoiler markup is important for users who are worried about spoilers, but I can also say that, especially on the mobile SE platform, I find it annoying to constantly click "Show Spoiler".  I am almost never worried about spoilers in the body of an SFF.SE question I choose to click on, and I imagine there are many other users who feel the sameway.

TV Tropes has resolved the tension between users who are annoyed by spoiler markup by allowing them to select an option in their profile to show spoilers by default, thus making the massive amounts of time wasted on that website slightly more pleasurable for people who don't care about spoilers.

I would like to see such an option implemented here, but I know very little about coding, or how the SE platform works, which leads me to ask the question:

1. Is it feasible to allow users to have an option that would ignore text marked up as a spoiler, and show it as regular body text instead?  (By feasible, I mean could such a feature be easily integrated into the SE platform?)
2. Provided the technical challenge is minimal (which may be a big IF), are there any reasons NOT to provide this option?

Comment: anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Downvotes in meta merely indicate disagreement.  I downvoted because I disagree such a feature would be useful enough to merit the development effort.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a workaround.  If you're using Chrome or Firefox, go install the [Stylish extension](https://userstyles.org/).  This extension lets you customize the rendering of webpages by overriding their CSS.  Then write a style for scifi.stackexchange.com with this code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("scifi.stackexchange.com") {
  .spoiler {
     color: #393318 !important;
  }
}
```

You can create another style for meta.scifi.stackexchange.com with this code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("meta.scifi.stackexchange.com") {
  .spoiler {
     color: #EEE !important;
  }
}
```

This will make spoilers just show up without interacting.  AFAIK, there's no way to accomplish this on mobile devices, which you mention in your question, but this works for computers.

The above is how I accomplish creating user CSS in Firefox.  [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/465964/94278) indicates for Chrome, you instead select “Manage installed styles” then click “Write new style”, then below the code box enter scifi.stackexchange.com to tell Stylish which site to apply the style to, then put the inner bit of CSS into your style:

```
.spoiler {
   color: #393318 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is probably down to my technical inability, but I just installed Stylish on Chrome and added this script and this hasn't been working for me.

Comment: @eliyahu-g have you tried asking on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or similar?

Comment: I've also installed it and it's not working for me...Here is a test question by the way:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19162/3804

Comment: Y'all using Chrome?  See the bit I added at the end.

Answer (score -1):

I don't mind spoilers. In fact, I often actively seek them out. But others don't and remaining spoiler-free is essential for an optimal viewing experience for many.

I can handle one click if it preserves a semblance of courtesy.

Comment: That's why I'm proposing an option which allows those who mind spoilers to retain the current viewing experience, while creating a different viewing experience for those who don't mind them (much as TV Tropes has).

Comment: I'm proposing an option; not advocating for the elimination of spoiler markup (which I would oppose)

Comment: As a spoilerphile, I don't mind it when a post has **one** block of spoiler-protected text, but it's annoying when there are several such blocks, and I can only make one visible at a time. I wuppose one way around that would be to go into edit mode, edit out the exclamation points, and cancel the edit when I'm done reading. Seems like a lot of trouble.

Comment: @user14111 At least in my browser, I can click on a spoiler block and it remains visible. YMMV.

Comment: @alexwlchan Works for me too. I wasn't smart enough to think of clicking. Thanks!